# javascript input only numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `input` that only allows number. but if I do copy paste something else then number it will allow it.

How can I make sure that he only allows number and nothing else (even after copy paste)

```html
<input type="text" name="people" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```

Comment: You can use `<input type="number" />`

Comment: You need to filter text itself, not keystrokes. But if you want to do it right (e.g. not moving caret randomly) it can easily get rather complex. With HTML5 it's possible that it's not worth any more.

Comment: FYI: You mean you want to only allow _digits_, not _numbers_. `1.23` and `1e+27` are both _numbers_, but according to your script example this is not what you want to allow.

Comment: Yes only digits

Comment: You can find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479505/1441822